# Private Ruby Gem Server with Authentication

Tags: ruby, authentication, rubygems

I want to install a private Ruby gem server with some authentication. I want to be able to host in-house gems using a public Ubuntu server.

I read about http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18. But there is no authentication with that one - as I can see.

Then I read about https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox. But when I use the basic authentication (they have in their Wiki), it complaints about fetching the sources from my server.

So. How can I make a private Ruby gem server with authentication? Is that just impossible?

Thanks.

Edit:

Geminabox problem. I try to "bundle" to install new gems... but it gives me this error:

> AGs-MacBook-Pro:super_app AG$ bundle
>
> Fetching source index for http:// rubygems.org/
>
> Fetching source index for http:// localhost:9292/
>
> Could not reach rubygems repository http:// rubygems.org/, http:// localhost:9292/
>
> Could not find aglipsum-0.0.1 in any of the sources

And "aglipsum" is my custom gem. However when I do not have basic authentication on, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Some professional binary repository managers, such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/RubyGems+Repository), support private RubyGems repositories.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried prefixing the source url with your basic auth credentials:

```
gem sources -a http://user:password@localhost:9292
```

This works for me with an apache + passanger setup.

Answer (score 1):

Bundler version 1.6 added support for HTTP auth via bundle config.

Comment: Upgrading from 1.5.1 to 1.7.x solved my problem with geminabox + auth.

Answer (score 0):

take a look if my fork of geminabox is what you need.
I add the authentication for managing gems.

https://github.com/poshboytl/geminabox

Answer (score 0):

## Deploy private rubygems repository

You can easily setup private rubygems repository from [geminabox](https://hub.docker.com/r/spoonest/geminabox/) docker image:

```
docker run -d -v /path_where_to_store_gems:/webapps/geminabox/data --name geminabox -p 9292:9292 -P -h geminabox -e PRIVATE=true -e USERNAME=myuser -e PASSWORD=mypassword spoonest/geminabox:latest
```

don't forget to change:

- `/path_where_to_store_gems` - path on your local machine where you want to store your gems
- `myuser` - username
- `mypassword` - password

That's all. Your repository is accessible by url **http://YOUR_HOST:9292**

## Installing gems form private repository

Add following line at the top of your `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://myuser:mypassword@YOUR_HOST:9292'
```

... and use `bundle install` as usual.