# Can I publish a gem to RubyGems but temporarily keep it "private"?

Tags: rubygems

I need to publish a gem to RubyGems that will eventually become fully public, but I'd like to keep it private in some way for a few weeks.

Private could be "not appear in search results" or could be more completely obscure (but I don't need password protection).

I need to do this so that a few people I select can test the RubyGems-based install process before I release widely.

Answer (score 1):

Basically no, but you can always generate the gem-file with Bundler via `rake build`
and `rake install` before you release it, and install it just locally on your machine.

Another way to do this is to use a Git repository for your Gem source code, and use the following in your `Gemfile`:

```
 gem 'yourgem', :git => 'git://github.com/youraccount/yourgem.git'
```

so it just installs the gem from your Git repository, instead of using a published Gem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have to publish it on the public RubyGems server in this case. You can setup private rubygems repository for your experiments on your local machine.

I've already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37015323/3849241) how to setup local private rubygems repository in 2 minutes with [geminabox](https://hub.docker.com/r/spoonest/geminabox/) Docker image.

Enjoy!