# Is there a way to make a private Ruby gem w/out having to set up a server?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, private

I'm working on a project that requires the use of another gem. I want to make this gem, however I'm aware that when a gem is created, it can get synchronized w/ RubyGems and made public, which I do not want. I'm also aware that a private server can be set up w/ utilities such as Gem In A Box, but I also want to avoid doing this if I can. Is there a way to simply set up a gem to not synch w/ RubyGems?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [RubyGems documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#first-gem)?

Comment: Yes, I have @toro2k. I just want to be sure on one point though, the gem will not be made public unless I (or someone else) pushes it to RubyGems through a `gem push`, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always just reference a gem in a `Gemfile` using a direct path, eg:

```
gem 'extracted_library', :path => './vendor/extracted_library'
```

You can also use a git archive. See [the Gemfile docs](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html) for more details.

This may help with your situation (I'm not sure of your exact setup).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily setup private gem server in 2 minutes with [geminabox](https://hub.docker.com/r/spoonest/geminabox/) docker image. Check out [my answer how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37015323/3849241).

Then you can add another one source to your `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://myuser:mypassword@YOUR_HOST:9292'
```

All public gems will be taken from RubyGems and all private gems will be installed from your private server.